# Would it be feasible to make a planet out of asteroids?

Tags: science-based, planets, terraforming, asteroids

Would it be feasible to make a planet out of asteroids taken from the solar system? It can only be made from objects less than 3 kilometers in radius inside the solar system. The way i'm thinking of getting it to work is by getting ships to take them close enough together that they can be bound using metal cabling & winches to pull them together. The total goal size of this planet is a ~800km radius. It needs to be one whole solid body, with enough structural stability to build significantly large buildings on it. Would this be possible?

Comment: FYI, for a solid body of ~400km radius, you only need one asteroid, [1 Ceres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceres_(dwarf_planet)). It's not a planet, though.

Comment: *"Make a planet out of asteroids taken from the asteroid belt":* That would be a **very small** tiny planet -- the total mass of the asteroid belt is about 4% of the mass of the Moon, or 0.5% of the mass of Earth.

Comment: @AlexP that was left over from before i checked how much mass is actually in there

Comment: I don't get it. You already have the Moon, solid and in one piece. Just move it to where you want it. Moving one big piece of rock is easier than moving lots of small pieces of the same total mass.

Comment: @AlexP Earth would probably be slightly upset that you stole their moon. Maybe it'd be better to go after one of the gas giant moons? Nobody's using Iapetus as far as I know...

Comment: @Cadence Depends where you want to move it, and how long you need it to last. Ice isn't code-approved for planet-building in past the Belt, and moving Iapetus into the inner solar system will void the warranty. Probably can make do for a couple dozen million years, though.

Comment: with such gravity 1/64 of the moon - even sand is a good foundation for a skyscraper,  considering there is no atmosphere and winds. earthquakes - those, I guess, are not that possible in this situation, even considering it a freshly stacked pile of gravel - but they are probably the biggest concern in this situation, hm but not so much loose soil on top is not a great wave conductor, so yeah, probably nothing to worry about

Comment: If you build it in the asteroid belt, be careful because it will pull in its neighboring asteroids. And if you want to move it to a safer orbit, make sure your colonists have enough budget for the fuel it will take to do so: You'll have to exhaust an absolutely bonkers amount of energy to change its orbit in any meaning full way. (To make the orbit larger you'll need to accelerate the planet, and to make smaller decelerate it. Trying to literally push it further out or closer in won't work: Doing so will simply introduce eccentricity to the orbit.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. We don't know the exact weight of the Oort cloud, but it is likely more than 1 earth mass. Some estimates are more than 5 earth masses. That means enough asteroids to slam together and make a planet.

Edit: just checked, the Oort cloud is technically part of the solar system.

Comment: Some estimates are much higher, some have proposed a gas giant in the Oort.

Answer (score 0):

**No**

Can a body with an 800 km radius be theoretically constructed out of "spare parts" in the solar system?  As per Demingan's answer, yes.  It will not need to be held together with cables, the whole point is that a body of sufficient size will form into a basically spherical shape as a result of its own gravity.

However, it will not be a *planet*.  While the pathway to determining the [definition of a planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definition_of_planet) has been long and contested, the criteria are well defined.

> A "planet" is a celestial body that: (a) is in orbit around the Sun,
> (b) has sufficient mass for its self-gravity to overcome rigid body
> forces so that it assumes a hydrostatic equilibrium (nearly round)
> shape, and (c) has cleared the neighbourhood around its orbit.

Given that the proposed object is smaller than [Pluto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluto), which famously lost its "planet" status, it would be considered a dwarf planet:

> A "dwarf planet" is a celestial body that: (a) is in orbit around the
> Sun, (b) has sufficient mass for its self-gravity to overcome rigid
> body forces so that it assumes a hydrostatic equilibrium (nearly
> round) shape, (c) has not cleared the neighbourhood around its orbit,
> and (d) is not a satellite.

This may seem like a petty distinction, but depending on the reason you want a "planet" it may be critical that the construct is too small to clear its own orbit.

As an additional safety note to planning authorities on constructed dwarf planets - bringing a whole heap of rocks together and letting gravity crush them into a single body will release a lot of heat.  Wait until the outer layers have cooled before starting to build structures.  (The core will take a long time to cool down.)

Comment: Re "A "planet" is a celestial body that: (a) is in orbit around the Sun...", that definition is simply wrong.  Per NASA, there are something over 4000 known planets that do not orbit the sun, and more are being discovered all the time: https://exoplanets.nasa.gov/faq/6/how-many-exoplanets-are-there/

Comment: @jamesqf Presumably they meant “a star”, or they are being strict about using “exoplanet” for planets orbiting stars other than Sol.

Comment: @StephenS: There are other reasons as well, that's just the most obvious.  The "clear its own orbit" is also nonsense, added as part of a personal vendetta against the discoverer of Pluto.

Comment: @jamesqf If you remove that requirement, then Ceres and Charon are “planets” too. You gotta draw the line somewhere, and that’s a rather bright line.

Comment: @StephenS: Actually it's not all that bright, since (depending on just how you define "cleared") several accepted planets have not cleared their orbits.  Neptune's orbit intersects that of Pluto, Jupiter has its Trojans, &c.  And what exactly is wrong with Ceres being a planet?  Unlike Vesta, it meets the hydrostatic equilibrium condition.

Answer (score 0):

> Q. Would it be feasible to make a planet out of asteroids taken from the solar system?

**A. No, not really. *Unless you want it to be*, then yes.**

I'll be honest, that answer sounds like cheating, and it is, but I have a very good reason for saying it.

First some background: As others have mentioned, it would be physically and financially difficult to undertake such a project. For reference, we can consider the cost it took to build the Death Star in Star Wars.

People have estimated that it would have taken a literally-galactic sized economy to build the Death Star. (We’re talking about 11 *thousand* times the GDP of our entire plant just to procure the steel needed to build its hull. And the other costs grow increasingly from there.)

Here is a great video on this subject, which provides an understanding of the costs and unexpected factors involved in building such a large object: [Film Theory: Luke SHOULDN'T Destroy The Death Star (Star Wars)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s4Y3dlTDAxw) (Warning: This youtuber is very interesting, so be careful not to get sucked into watching video after video after video...)

So based on this, **it’s clearly not possible** for one planet to manufacture a Death Star—and keep in mind, the first Death Star was about 150 times *smaller* in volume than the planet you are proposing.

So wait. Why then did I say it's possible? How can this be?

Well, it’s entirely because of ✨World Building✨

If you choose to pursue a **Hard World Building** narrative structure, then producing a man-made planet becomes a hard problem to tackle. However, if instead you pursue a **Soft World Building** narrative structure, then you’re only limited by your imagination and the story you want to tell.

To get an idea for how Hard and Soft world building are different, I would *highly* recommend this youtube video: It is (in my opinion) an absolutely eye-opening experience for an author/world-builder: [Hard Worldbuilding vs. Soft Worldbuilding / A Study of Studio Ghibli](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gcyrrTud3x4)

So in short, yes, you can choose to get hung up on the logistics of building a planet, OR you can completely omit that detail and instead choose to focus on the character-driven story which takes place on that man-made planet.

Good luck!